# Conditional Fade inside an Append

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a conditional statement for fadein. Basically if that value is true, apply and if false, not.

There's a logic on my block but it doesn't work as expected.

```
var table = $('<table></table>');
table.append($('<tr>')
.append($('<td>')
    .addClass('col2 linhaSub')
        .append($('<span>')
            .text(modelo.ListaRegistros[3][0].ID)
            if(modelo.ListaRegistros[3][0].Efeito== true)
            {
            .fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300)
            }

        )
)
```

I'm getting: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Is that any way to perform what I'm trying instead of putting the whole append for both situations? (with and without the fade effect)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reference your span via a variable:

```
var $table = $('<table></table>');
var $span = $('<span>').text(modelo.ListaRegistros[3][0].ID);

$table.append($('<tr>')
    .append($('<td>')
    .addClass('col2 linhaSub')
    .append($span);

if (modelo.ListaRegistros[3][0].Efeito== true) {
    $span.fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300);
 }
```

I renamed your `table` variable to indicate it's a jQuery object.  Obviously feel free to play around with it; the main point here is that you needed that variable to call `fadeIn()` on.

Comment: So I need to add an ID to this SPAN that I'm appending?

Comment: @Dan-SP No, you just need to change `.fadeIn(300)` to `table.fadeIn(300)`

Comment: But I need to fade the SPAN content not the whole table

Comment: Now it makes sense ! The point is that I will have loads of spans over the screen.. hehe

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You can't include an if statement when chaining those functions.

```
var table = $('<table></table>');
table.append($('<tr>')
 .append($('<td>')
    .addClass('col2 linhaSub')
        .append($('<span>').text(modelo.ListaRegistros[3][0].ID)));
if(modelo.ListaRegistros[3][0].Efeito== true)
{
    $(".linhaSub span").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300);
}
```

Comment: The point is that I will add `.linhaSub span` onto registers that will be false too.. But I came to an idea. Maybe I can add a toggleClass ( that has a conditional parameter and after rendering the whole table, I place a fade on all those new classes. I will try that.

Comment: Looks like  `$(".linhaSub span")` doesn't affect the created span.. are you sure its right?

Comment: Can you please post some HTML? I can't fully help you with this without seeing it. What element are you wanting to show?